# Run tests on https://ci.testling.com/ with Karma.js?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, karma-runner, tap

I'm trying to run my Karma tests on https://ci.testling.com/, is it possible?

I thought that usage of TAP (https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-tape-reporter) reporter will provide such possibility but unfortunately, `testling` fails with error `not ok 1 Error: SyntaxError: Parse error on line 6699`.

If no.. please advice me some service that could run Karma tests? I'm on Mac and would like to run them on Windows IE for example.

Answer (score 0):

`testling` has actually been unavailable since July 2014:
https://github.com/substack/testling/issues/88